# Sound effect when mouse hovers over object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So i'm trying to set up this thing where a sound effect is made whenever the player "hovers" their mouse above a label.
This is the image: https://gyazo.com/ca251495b348ab8cd27f7328c84518e8

I've tried looking for solutions, I have found one previously but it did not work when adding sound to it.

```
import math, random, sys
import enum
import pygame, time
from pygame.locals import*
from sys import exit
from pygame import mixer

#initialising python
pygame.init()
#pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100,16,2,4096)
mixer.init()

#define display
W, H = 1600,900
HW, HH = (W/2), (H/2)
AREA = W * H


#bsound effects
buttonsound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("ButtonSound1.wav") 


#initialising display
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DS = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
FPS = 54
progress = 0
background = pygame.Surface(DS.get_size())
smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("century gothic",25)


#background image
bg = pygame.image.load("Daytime.jpg").convert()
loadingimg = pygame.image.load("LoadingScreen.png").convert()
pause = pygame.image.load("Pause screen.png").convert()
gameover = pygame.image.load("Game Over.png").convert()
mainmenu = pygame.image.load("Main_Menu4.png").convert()
#mainmenu = pygame.transform.smoothscale(mainmenu, (W,H))
loadingimg = pygame.transform.smoothscale(loadingimg, (W,H))

#define some colours
BLACK = (0,0,0,255)
WHITE = (255,255,255,255)
green = (0,140,0)
grey = (180,180,180)

walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('Moving1.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving2.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving3.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving4.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving5.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving6.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving7.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving8.png'), pygame.image.load('Moving9.png')]
walkRight = []
for i in walkLeft:
    walkRight.append(pygame.transform.flip(i, True, False))


char = pygame.image.load('Moving1.png').convert_alpha()
char2 = pygame.image.load('Moving1.png').convert_alpha()
char2 = pygame.transform.flip(char2, True, False)

x = 0
y = 500
height = 40
width = 87
vel = 5
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
left = False
right = False
walkCount = 0
run = True


# FUNCTIONS
def event_handler():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

# === CLASSES === (CamelCase names)

class Button():

    def __init__(self, text, x=0, y=0, width=100, height=50, command=None):

        self.text = text
        self.command = command

        self.image_normal = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image_normal.fill(green)

        self.image_hovered = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        #buttonsound1.play()

        self.image = self.image_normal
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 15)


        text_image = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
        text_rect = text_image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)

        self.image_normal.blit(text_image, text_rect)
        self.image_hovered.blit(text_image, text_rect)

        # you can't use it before `blit` 
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)

        self.hovered = False
        #self.clicked = False

    def update(self):

        if self.hovered:
            buttonsound1.play()
        else:
            self.image = self.image_normal

    def draw(self, surface):

        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def handle_event(self, event):

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            self.hovered = self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
            buttonsound1.play()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.hovered:
                buttonsound1.play()
                print('Clicked:', self.text)
                if self.command:
                    self.command()


class GameState( enum.Enum ):
    Loading = 0
    Menu = 1
    Settings = 2
    Playing = 3
    GameOver = 4

#set the game state initially.
game_state = GameState.Loading


#LOADING
def text_objects(text, color, size):
    if size == "small":
        textSurface = smallfont.render(text, True, color)

    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def loading(progress):
    if progress < 100:
        text = smallfont.render("Loading: " + str(int(progress)) + "%", True, WHITE)
    else:
        text = smallfont.render("Loading: " + str(100) + "%", True, WHITE)

    DS.blit(text, [50, 660])

def message_to_screen(msh, color, y_displace = 0, size = "small"):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, color, size)
    textRect.center = HW, HH + y_displace
    DS.blit(textSurf, textRect)

while (progress/4) < 100:
    event_handler()
    DS.blit(loadingimg, (0,0))
    time_count = (random.randint(1,1))
    increase = random.randint(1,20)
    progress += increase
    pygame.draw.rect(DS, green, [50, 700, 402, 29])
    pygame.draw.rect(DS, grey, [50, 701, 401, 27])
    if (progress/4) > 100:
        pygame.draw.rect(DS, green, [50, 700, 401, 28])
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(DS, green, [50, 700, progress, 28])
    loading(progress/4)
    pygame.display.flip()

    time.sleep(time_count)

#changing to menu
game_state = GameState.Menu


Menumusic = pygame.mixer.music.load("MainMenu.mp3")
Menumusic = pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

def main_menu():
    DS.blit(mainmenu, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

    btn1 = Button('Hello', 812.5, 250, 100, 50)
    btn2 = Button('World', 825, 325, 100, 50)
    btn3 = Button('Hello', 825, 450, 100, 50)
    btn4 = Button('World', 825, 575, 100, 50)
    btn5 = Button('World', 825, 675, 100, 50)
    btn6 = Button('Hello', 825, 790, 100, 50)

    while run:
        event_handler()
        btn1.update()
        btn2.update()

        # --- draws ---

        btn1.draw(DS)
        btn2.draw(DS)
        btn3.draw(DS)
        btn4.draw(DS)
        btn5.draw(DS)
        btn6.draw(DS)



    pygame.display.update()

main_menu()
```

What I'm expecting is a sound effect to be made whenever the mouse goes over a label, however, the output from the program is that nothing plays or happens.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is the processing of the events in `event_handler()`, which consumes *all* the events.  Then the `Button` class `handle_event()` function is starved of events (also this function is never called).  It's a good idea to handle events in a single place in the code, and call out from there.

If the OP's code did work, it looks to be constantly re-playing the sounds too.  The mouse-move generates *a lot* of events, so the triggering of playing the sound needs to only play on the initial entry into the button's rectangle.  Whereas the mouse movement handler is re-playing on *every* event inside the button's `rect`.

Below is some example code where I took your buttons, and modified them to handle the hovering in a "edge-triggered" manner.  This means it only triggers when the "hovered" state first becomes true, not *while* it's true (which would be "level-triggered")

Note: It does not actually play the sound, as I don't have a sound-file handy.  It just does a `print()`.

```
import pygame

#initialising python
pygame.init()
#pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100,16,2,4096)
pygame.mixer.init()

#define display
W, H = 200, 200
HW, HH = (W/2), (H/2)
AREA = W * H

#initialising display
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DS = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
#pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0) )
FPS = 54

#define some colours
BLACK = (0,0,0,255)
WHITE = (255,255,255,255)
green = (0,140,0)
grey = (180,180,180)


class Button():

    def __init__(self, text, x=0, y=0, width=100, height=50, command=None):

        self.text = text
        self.command = command
        self.image_normal = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image_normal.fill(green)
        self.image_hovered = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image_hovered.fill(grey)
        self.image  = self.image_normal
        self.rect   = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.hovered= False  # is the mouse over this button?

    def update(self):
        pass

    def handleMouseOver( self, mouse_position ):
        """ If the given co-ordinate inside our rect,
            Do all the mouse-hovering work             """
        # Check button position against mouse
        # Change the state *once* on entry/exit
        if ( self.mouseIsOver( mouse_position ) ):
            if ( self.hovered == False ):
                self.image = self.image_hovered
                self.hovered = True   # edge-triggered, not level triggered
                # Do we want to check pygame.mixer.get_busy() ?
                if ( pygame.mixer.get_busy() == False ):
                    print( self.text + " DO buttonsound1.play() ")
        else:
            if ( self.hovered == True ):
                self.image = self.image_normal
                self.hovered = False

    def mouseIsOver( self, mouse_position ):
        """ Is the given co-ordinate inside our rect """
        return self.rect.collidepoint( mouse_position )

    def draw(self, surface):

        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)


def main_menu():

    run = True
    btn1 = Button('Hello1',  50,  50, 40, 40)
    btn2 = Button('World2', 100,  50, 40, 40)
    btn3 = Button('Hello3',  50, 100, 40, 40)
    btn4 = Button('World4', 100, 100, 40, 40)

    # Put the buttons into a list so we can loop over them, simply
    buttons = [ btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4 ]

    while run:

        # draw the buttons
        for b in buttons:
            b.draw( DS ) # --- draws ---

        # Handle events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                mouse_position = event.pos
                for b in buttons:
                    b.handleMouseOver( mouse_position )
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_position = event.pos
                for b in buttons:
                    if ( b.mouseIsOver( mouse_position ) ):
                        print('Clicked:', b.text)
                        #if b.command:
                        #    b.command()


        pygame.display.update()



main_menu()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: This really helped man thank you so much. Last question though: how do i make the buttons invisible?

Comment: @TheForeigner - Perhaps just don't draw them?  This is for your on-screen menu I guess - When creating the button, use `pygame.Surface.copy()` to clip the appropriate section form your menu background where the button needs to go.  I guess you still need the highlight "hover" version too, maybe you can create these button images separately, and load them in.  (or have an image same as the background, except with highlighted menu-items, and clip the "hover" image at the same co-ordinates)